# compare two same armature structure, rotate first armature's bone to the second position

Tags: python, animation, armature, bones

I have two armature, each has the same bone structure, but the bones' location, length, and rotation is different, how to write python script to modify first armature, make first same with the second?

I want to copy the second Armature's bone position into the first one's pose mode. Not  copy in edit mode.

I try these code:

```
restPoseBone = bpy.data.objects["Armature"].pose.bones["Bip01"]
otherPoseBone = bpy.data.objects["Armature2"].pose.bones["Bip01"]
restPoseBone.length = otherPoseBone.length
restPoseBone.rotation_quaternion = ??
```

how to calculate the rotation_quaternion for the pose bone?

this is a demo blender file, I want to copy "Armature2" edit mode position to "Armature" pose mode.

testArmature.blend 
http://pasteall.org/blend/31724

Comment: What do you want to calculate? Assigning `restPoseBone.rotation_quaternion = otherPoseBone.rotation_quaternion` works for me

Comment: the two armature only has same structure, but all bones have different edit mode position, I just want to make the second armature's edit mode position as the pose mode position for first armature.

Answer (score 1):

The following python code copies the bone configuration from the active object to all selected armatures. You do not need to bother with rotation matrix here because the bones are defined in local space, thus the global rotation of the armatures does not need to be taken into account:

```
import bpy

# Assume, that context.object is an armature
context = bpy.context
scene   = context.scene
source  = context.object

# Targets are all other selected armatures
targets = [a for a in context.selected_objects if a != source and a.type=='ARMATURE']

# Store the bone data of source:
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bone_store = []
for ebone in source.data.edit_bones:
    bone_store.append([ebone.name, ebone.head.copy(), ebone.tail.copy(), ebone.roll])
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')


for target in targets:
    scene.objects.active = target
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    # Transfer the bones to the other armature.
    # The following works because the bone data is defined in local space:

    ebones = target.data.edit_bones
    for bone_data in bone_store:
        bid =  bone_data[0]
        if bid in ebones:
            ebone      = ebones[bid]
            ebone.head = bone_data[1].copy()
            ebone.tail = bone_data[2].copy()
            ebone.roll = bone_data[3]

    # Note: You might also want to copy constraints

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

scene.objects.active = source
```

And here is a snippet that copies only the pose from one armature to the other:

```
import bpy

# Assume, that context.object is an armature
context = bpy.context
scene   = context.scene
source  = context.object

# Targets are all other selected armatures
targets = [a for a in context.selected_objects if a != source and a.type=='ARMATURE']

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action="SELECT")
bpy.ops.pose.copy()

for target in targets:
    scene.objects.active = target
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
    bpy.ops.pose.paste()
```

Comment: if I don't want to change edit bones' head, tail, roll, I want to change pose bone's data , how can i do that?

Comment: oops, my fault. Copy the pose is implemented in Blender: select your source object, go to pose mode, select all bones, then press CTRL C, switch over to the target armature, enter pose mode, then press CTRL V. I add another snippet for python in a moment.

Comment: I can not find how to download the blendfile from that page. Could you post it to http://pasteall.org/blend instead ?

Comment: yes, this file thanks. http://pasteall.org/blend/31724, I have find a method to copy one armature edit mode bone position to another armature pose mode. I will paste the code here.

Comment: I tried the above code to copy from one armature in some rest position to a different posed armature also in the rest position. But, I see no changes, the pose remains the same. The pose is not changed at all. And the above script throws errors, I think python is not happy with spaces or tabs introduced by extra formatting.

Comment: I've did more testing and fixing on the script and I got it working by removing some spaces and tabs and new lines. But it seems because it copies the bones in Edit mode, those are just moved in another location are not re-posed. Which I assume the original question was asking. After I copy with the above script the pose from active to selected then reseting the pose is not working. I assume this is because the script was working in EDIT mode not pose mode.